# Why do we use compression for discrete siganls?

Tags: discrete-signals, compression

Time compression/expansion (also called dilation) maps the input discrete signal
$x$ to the output discrete signal $y$ as given by :
$$
y[n]=x[\alpha n]
$$
When $\alpha>1$, the signal experiences compression. My question is :

> Why would compression ever be used for discrete-time signals when it would result in the loss of information (sample points)? How would this be beneficial?

Comment: *time compression and expansion* operations are a consequence of digital sample-rate conversion algorithms. Upsamplers, Interpolators, Decimators, Downsamplers require the use of time compresseion or expansion expressions.

Comment: thank you very much for your comment I will definitely take a look at them.